# How to randomize an array of bit arrays in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new to Verilog.

How can I randomize the following:

```
 bit [7:0] data [];
```

*Without use randomize() of systemVerilog.

Comment: Your question says you are new to Verilog, but you are asking how to randomize a dynamic array, which is a SystemVerilog data type.  Perhaps you should change that to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SystemVerilog will not change the size of a dynamic array unless you put a constraint on it. So you either need to allocate the array before calling `randomize()`,  or use a constraint to randomize the size.

```
bit [7:0] data [];

data = new[10];
randomize(data);
```

or

```
bit [7:0] data [];

randomize(data) with {data.size inside {[5:15]} ;};
```

or if you do not have access to the randomize() SystemVerilog, you can do

```
  data = new[10];
  foreach(data[ii]) data[ii] = $urandom;
```

Comment: @Rahul Menon- I know that there is a special method in systemVerilog (randomize), buy I have asked in Verilog.

Comment: You asked in Verilog, but your example showed the SystemVerilog `bit` type and you used the SystemVerilog tag. I added an answer without using `randomize()`.

Comment: @dave_59 isn't dynamic arrays system-verilog  construct ?

Comment: @RahulMenon, Yes. But if you are using Modelsim, all the latest versions of Modelsim support all SystemVerilog data types. You need Questa for randomize() support

Answer (score 2):

constrain the size of the array to the required range and call randomize. It should generate an array with random data ( in the example below of size between 30 and 40 )

```
class rand_gen ;

rand bit [7:0]   data[];
constraint db { data.size inside  {[30:40]}; }

task generate ();
 randomize(data);
end task

endclass
```